# Text view values doesn't appear

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio, phpmyadmin

The Text view doesn't display the value

This is the Java code (CompstatusFragment)

```
package com.example.loginregister;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress;
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.reloc.org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.reloc.org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.reloc.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.reloc.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

public class CompstatusFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView fullnameTextView, emailTextView, complaint_idTextView, spinnercategoryTextView, spinnersubcategoryTextView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compstatus, container, false);

        // Update variable assignments
        fullnameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        emailTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        complaint_idTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.complaint_id);
        spinnercategoryTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);
        spinnersubcategoryTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSubcategory);

        new Connection().execute();
        return view;
    }

    class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String result = "";
            String servername = "http://192.168.0.9/loginregister/status.php";
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(servername));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                reader.close();
                result = stringBuffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "There exception" + e.getMessage();
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
                int success = jsonResult.getInt("success");
                if (success == 1) {
                    JSONArray statusArray = jsonResult.getJSONArray("status");
                    // Sort the statusArray by timestamp
                    JSONArray sortedArray = sortArrayByTimestamp(statusArray);

                    if (sortedArray.length() > 0) {
                        JSONObject status = sortedArray.getJSONObject(sortedArray.length() - 1);

                        int users_id = status.getInt("users_id");
                        String fullnameStr = status.getString("fullname");
                        String emailStr = status.getString("email");
                        int complaintID = status.getInt("complaintID");
                        String categoryStr = status.getString("category");
                        String subcategoryStr = status.getString("subcategory");

                        // Set the values to the TextViews using the correct TextView variables
                        fullnameTextView.setText("Fullname: " + fullnameStr);
                        emailTextView.setText("E-mail: " + emailStr);
                        complaint_idTextView.setText("Complaint ID: " + complaintID);
                        spinnercategoryTextView.setText("Category: " + categoryStr);
                        spinnersubcategoryTextView.setText("Sub-category: " + subcategoryStr);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private JSONArray sortArrayByTimestamp(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            // Implement sorting logic based on timestamp
            // This is a placeholder, replace with your actual sorting logic
            return jsonArray;  // Placeholder: returning the original array as-is
        }
    }
}
```

This is the (compstatus.xml) code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".CompstatusFragment">

    <!-- First Box: Complaint Progress and Details -->

    <!-- Header Title for Second Box: NOTIFICATIONS -->

    <!-- Second Box: Notifications List with Dates -->

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstBox"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="181dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/outline"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.218"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!-- Circle Percentage Chart -->

        <!-- Complaint Details -->

        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
            android:id="@+id/progresscircle"
            android:layout_width="139dp"
            android:layout_height="143dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="232dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fullname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Fullname:"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:text="E-mail:"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.471"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/complaint_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/complaint_id"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.538"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinnerCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Category:"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/complaint_id" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSubcategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Sub-Category:"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.537"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the php code for the CompstatusFragment (status.php)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "loginregister";

// Create a connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(!$conn){
    die ("ERROR in connection: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$response = array();

$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM status";
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response['success'] = 1;
    $status=array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        # code...
        array_push($status,$row);
    }
    $response['status'] = $status;
}
else{
    $response['success'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = 'No data';
}
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The value for fullname, email, complaintID, category, subcategory display from the mysql.

if I try to run the code there is no error for the code.

I already try to check on ChatGPT they said no issues, but the display still not come out.